# Android Studio fails to recognise &lt; and &gt; tags

Tags: java, html, android-studio, compiler-errors, tags

Android Studio wont recognize html tags, they're highlighted in red, it says " cannot resolve symbol 'gt' " and the project wont build. Does anyone know why exactly and how I could fix this? Any input whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error :

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:166: error: ')' expected
        if(songPosn& lt; 0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
                       ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:166: error: not a statement
        if(songPosn& lt; 0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
                         ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:166: error: ';' expected
        if(songPosn& lt; 0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
                          ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:173: error: ')' expected
        if(songPosn& gt; =songs.size()) songPosn=0;
                       ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:173: error: illegal start of expression
        if(songPosn& gt; =songs.size()) songPosn=0;
                         ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:173: error: ';' expected
        if(songPosn& gt; =songs.size()) songPosn=0;
                                      ^
6 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:166: error: ')' expected
        if(songPosn& lt; 0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
                       ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:166: error: not a statement
        if(songPosn& lt; 0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
                         ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:166: error: ';' expected
        if(songPosn& lt; 0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
                          ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:173: error: ')' expected
        if(songPosn& gt; =songs.size()) songPosn=0;
                       ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:173: error: illegal start of expression
        if(songPosn& gt; =songs.size()) songPosn=0;
                         ^
/home/zerodavila/AndroidStudioProjects/ZLayer4 (another copy)/app/src/main/java/com/hivemind/zerodavila/zlayer4/MusicService.java:173: error: ';' expected
        if(songPosn& gt; =songs.size()) songPosn=0;
                                      ^
6 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 19.833 secs

Total time: 1 mins 19.833 secs
```

Comment: Where does is say this specifically?  Can you show us the file?  What type is that file?

Comment: java file, a background service and an activity, so basically everywhere, it shows in a pop-up when I hover over the tags. And when I try to build I get : Error:(173, 39) error: ';' expected
Error:(166, 24) error: ')' expected
Error:(166, 26) error: not a statement
Error:(166, 27) error: ';' expected
Error:(173, 24) error: ')' expected
Error:(173, 26) error: illegal start of expression
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Show us the actual text of that file, and enough text around the error to provide proper context.

Answer (score 1):

I droped the tags all together, replaced '& lt;' with < and '& gt;' with >, works fine.